# What's the benefit of defining Go methods away from struct definitions?

Tags: struct, go

Go allows one to define methods separately from the struct/datatype they work on. Does it mean just flexibility in placing the method definitions or something more?

I've heard Go's struct/methods system being compared to monkey patching, but if I understand correctly, then you really can't add methods to any existing type (struct), as methods must reside in same package as the type. Ie. you can monkey patch only the types which are under your control anyway. Or am I missing something?

In which cases would you define a type and its methods in separate source files (or in different parts of the same source file)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an advantage of Go over type based languages : you can organize your files as you like :

- you can put all the similar functions together, even if there are many receiver types
- you can split a file which would otherwise be too big

As frequently, Go didn't add a constraint which was useless. So the answer could also be *"why not"* ?

> you really can't add methods to any existing type (struct), as methods must reside in same package as the type

If you could, you might not be able to determine which function to call in case of the same function name used on the same struct in two different packages. Or that would make certain packages incompatible.

Answer (score 7):

This is (partly, probably) because in Go, you can have methods on *any* type, not just struct:

```
type Age uint

func (a Age) Add(n Age) Age {
  return a + n
}
```

This is also how you can add methods to an existing type. What you do is define a new type based on that existing type, and add methods as you like.

Comment: I don't see how it's adding methods to an existing type -- existing type here is "uint" and if I understand correctly "Add" won't work with "uint"-s.

Comment: Yeah, I took a shortcut, you can't add method to a type outside your package, but you can define a new type based on an existing one, and add methods to this type. It's then trivial to cast the base type into your augmented type to use these methods (for example what Go authors did with the StringSlice type in the sort package).

Answer (score 6):

Monkey Patching is not possible in go. The type you define methods on must reside in the same package.

What you can do is to define functions and methods wherever you like inside the package. It doesn't really matter if the type definition is in the same file as the method definition for the type.

This makes it possible to group all type definitions in one file and have the method implementation in another. Possibly with other helper which are needed by the methods.